# Internet Connection Network type is it wi-fi/ethernet or something else.How to find programmatically in windows 8 metro app c#

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am developing app for windows 8 surface device.
I need to find the internet connection type programmatically what i want to find is 
the device is **connected to wi-fi/LanConnection or some other network type.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find network type with `NetworkAdapter` class. It has property [IanaInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype.aspx). To check all the IANA interface, go [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ianaiftype-mib/ianaiftype-mib)

```
var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (profile != null)
{
    var interfaceType = profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType;

    // 71 is WiFi & 6 is Ethernet(LAN)
    if (interfaceType == 71 || interfaceType == 6)
    {
        //TODO:
    }
    // 243 & 244 is 3G/Mobile
    else if (interfaceType == 243 || interfaceType == 244)
    {
        //TODO:
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 WwanConnectionProfileDetails wlanConnectionProfileDetails = InternetConnectionProfile.WwanConnectionProfileDetails;

if (wlanConnectionProfileDetails != null)
{                            
status = true;
string accessPointName = wlanConnectionProfileDetails.HomeProviderId;
if (wlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass() == WwanDataClass.Edge || wlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass() == WwanDataClass.Gprs)
{
networkType = NetworkType.EDGE;
}
else if (wlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass() == wanDataClass.Hsdpa ||
wlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass() == WwanDataClass.Hsupa ||
wlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass() == WwanDataClass.Umts)
{
networkType = NetworkType.HSPA;
}
else if (wlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass() == WwanDataClass.LteAdvanced)
{
networkType = NetworkType.LTE;
}                            
}
```

This is how I did check type of data service connected to. Cheers!!